# Mongodb returns an empty array while retrieving data through nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

```
let mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    let express = require("express")
    let app = express()
    let connectionString = 'mongodb://ToDoAppUser:ToDoAppUserPassword@ac-u9kgapm-shard-00-00.8rdkdoi.mongodb.net:27017,ac-u9kgapm-shard-00-01.8rdkdoi.mongodb.net:27017,ac-u9kgapm-shard-00-02.8rdkdoi.mongodb.net:27017/?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-68qno6-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority'
    let db 
    mongodb.connect(connectionString,function(err,client){
     
      if (err) throw err
       db = client.db()
       app.listen(3000)
       console.log("Database connected.");
    
    })
    
    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : false}))
```

**Trying to retrieve data from MongodB**

As you can see that , I am trying to retrieve data from MongoDB collection named #item and want to print it. But it shows an empty array. I am stuck on this. kindly help me to resolve this issue.

```
    app.get("/", function(req, res){
      **// this collectio method of mongodb returns empty array.
      // however, mongodb got connected, but i cannot retreive data from mongodb**  
      db.collection('items').find().toArray(function(err, items) {
        if(err) console.log(err)
        console.log(items)
    
      })
```

Comment: Have you saved any items on the DB? did you make sure it persisted?

Comment: Yeah ,there are three documents . I added them

Comment: Is the collection named "item" or "items"?

Comment: collection name is items.

Comment: `db = client.db()` - you havent specified the database name. Maybe use the database name also - `db = client.db('some_database')`.

Comment: I checked that -prasad but it did not work for me

Comment: I think if you use string as name in collection call - put it to constant. That's the way to omit typo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following format.

```
async function findOneListingByName(client, nameOfListing) {
    const result = await client.db("sample_airbnb").collection("listingsAndReviews").findOne({ name: nameOfListing });

    if (result) {
        console.log(`Found a listing in the collection with the name '${nameOfListing}':`);
        console.log(result);
    } else {
        console.log(`No listings found with the name '${nameOfListing}'`);
    }
}
```

This code above is worked for me.
By the way, you can read their documentation here for more examples:
https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/javascript/node-crud-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the call to fetch items from DB is asynchronous, and you're trying to use items synchronous manner.

Try adding `async` to the controller function and using `await` for the DB request. Like this:

```
app.get("/", async function(req, res){
        /*  Mongo documents don't show any parameters for the toArray method
         * Read here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/#mongodb-method-cursor.toArray
         *
        */
       const itemsFromDB = await db.collection('items').find().toArray()
       conssole.log('items are:' itemsFromDB )

})
```

Comment: I tried it Haroon, this time it shows undefined.  Items are undefined

Comment: can you share the schema file and export for items. Plus also how you're importing the DB client instance( named `db`)

Comment: plus can you verify that client is connected and can identify a `items` Model? Just console.log('verification check',  await db.collection('items')) and check it's not undefined.

Comment: Implementing the code the way you showed , it shows that items are [function : Array] and if I implement async to my code , it shows items are undefined

Comment: Remove the `toArray` method from my example above and share what is returned

Comment: It returns nothing but after verificaiton check it shows gibberish something like that verification check Collection {
  s: {
    db: Db { s: [Object] },
    options: {
      raw: false,
      promoteLongs: true,
      promoteValues: true,
      promoteBuffers: false,
      ignoreUndefined: false,
      bsonRegExp: false,
      serializeFunctions: false,
      fieldsAsRaw: {},
      enableUtf8Validation: true,
      writeConcern: [WriteConcern],
      readPreference: [ReadPreference]
    },   and something like that goes for long ,it is just the first part

Comment: moreover, i want to add that i am using the mongodb version of 2.2 or later while connecting to the application in mongodb. As i am a beginner and following a Udemy course . But here i got that problem , database is connected as i checked the chart of connections.

Comment: Can you please share the whole schema file in the question?

Comment: I added these documents manually by inserting documents in mongodb.